# get shortcut for WinForm without having seperate project

Tags: c#, winforms, exe

I have a project with different Win Forms in it. I can open all the forms from one form which is executable of my current project. I am wondering if there chance to create something like a shortcut to open one of the forms not only from my main form but also just from file explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need to create an extra project, since the Main form always need to run, in order to keep your application running.

Comment: I was wondering if there chance to do it maybe with Threading or something like that, but seems like not

Comment: No, you can use threading for running other parts of your application, while your main application is still running

Comment: @Mobstaa, spawning a new form (from Program.cs or a parent form) will always start the form in a new thread. Your "Form1" thread is just called the "Main UI Thread" because it was made first.

Comment: Easiest way to achieve what you want, is creating a duplicate project, set the form you would like to show at startup(Program.cs) and remove the others.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a command line argument to a shortcut, and add code to your app that looks at the command line at startup time and opens a different form based on what the code finds.

Comment: also great idea, but unfortunately I am not able to create command line arguments for this project :(